# Produce parentheses around number of equation

Tags: formatting, cross-referencing, equations

Is there any direct command which can help me to put the number of a equation in the parentheses, for example if I write the following:

```
\begin{equation} \label{eq:1}
this is my equation 
\end{equation}

I need this equation: \ref{eq:1}
```

I need to produce the following

> I need this equation: (1)

I need that **(1)** .

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) What you need is `\eqref{eq:1}`; just load `\usepackage{amsmath}`

Comment: A second advantage of using the `\eqref` command, in addition to it placing parentheses around the equation number automatically (see egreg's comment), is that it will always typeset its argument in upright mode, even if the surrounding text happens to be typeset in italics. This is convenient if you're creating a cross-reference to an equation from within a theorem (or similar) environment, as the body of theorem statements are usually typeset in italics.